# Can't Append Child After Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is my JS

```
$('.data').click(function(){
  var datacontent = $(this).attr('data-content');
  $(this).parent().html('').append(`
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>${data[datacontent].content}</p>
      <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
      <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
    </div>
    `
   });
```

My full code :

```js
var data = [{
    "content": "first content"
  },
  {
    "content": "second content"
  }
];

$('.data').click(function() {
  var datacontent = $(this).attr('data-content');
  //alert (datacontent)

  $(this).parent().html('').append(`
    <div class="wrap">
        <p>${data[datacontent].content}</p>
     <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
      <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
      </div>
  `)
});
```

```css
.data {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    Hi, Please click data
  </p>
  <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
  <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
</div>
```

I cannot click data 2

I add previous HTML (`<div class="data" data-content="0">` and `<div class="data" data-content="1">`) in append.
Any idea to fix my issue?

Thank you

Comment: You're replacing the element that has the event handler bound to it, so you're losing the event handler.

Comment: I try this $(this).parent().append('/*code*/') but didn't work too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the `.data` elements that had the event handler attached to them.

It would be better if you just wrote into the `<p>` instead of rewriting the entire DIV.

```js
var data = [{
    "content": "first content"
  },
  {
    "content": "second content"
  }
];

$('.data').click(function() {
  var datacontent = $(this).data('content');
  //alert (datacontent)  
  $(this).siblings("p").text(data[datacontent].content)
});
```

```css
.data {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    Hi, Please click data
  </p>
  <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
  <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
</div>
```

If you really need to replace the whole thing, see [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
var data = [{
    "content": "first content"
  },
  {
    "content": "second content"
  }
];

//$('.data').click(function() {
$(document).on('click','.data', function(){
  var datacontent = $(this).attr('data-content');
  //alert (datacontent)

  $(this).parent().html('').append(`
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>${data[datacontent].content}</p>
      <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
      <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
    </div>
  `)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace whole html code, but just the siblings `p` tag only.

```js
var data = [{
    "content": "first content"
  },
  {
    "content": "second content"
  }
];

$('.data').on('click', function(e) {
  var datacontent = $(this).attr('data-content');
  $(this).siblings("p").html(data[datacontent].content)
});
```

```css
.data {
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    Hi, Please click data
  </p>
  <div class="data" data-content="0">data 1</div>
  <div class="data" data-content="1">data 2</div>
</div>
```